# Is Single Page Application needs a Application Server?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, application-server

I'm new to SPA development, so this may be a stupid question. please understand.

My question is "Is SPA(Single Page Application) needs a Application Server?"

As I understand it, the SPA gets the response after calling REST API. It use that response to re-render.
If so, is the server that handles REST API "Application Server"?

So many posts say Application Server are tomcat, oracle, etc... and they are also say Application Server handle the request to access the database. Then what is "Application Server" in SPA? or there are no Application Server in SPA?
(Are there any architectures or systems I'm not aware of?)

If I'm misunderstanding the architecture, please let me know.
I want to understand web server and Application Server in SPA. So I have read many posts but I'm still confused.

Thanks.

Comment: A SPA doesn't *need* an application server, but it *can* have one. Usually if you have any kind of dynamic content, features such as user logins, you name it, you will need an application server (a more common term for it is a back-end server!). There is a difference to be made between static SPA's and dynamic/user generated content SPA's

Comment: An SPA only represents the front end of the application, and it doesn't require a server, but as mentioned above by @nbokmans if you need any logic/dynamic content to be fetched you will want to set up a backend server to handle that, but note that the backend server is a seperate application from the SPA.

Comment: @nbokmans Thanks for the comment. They call it a back-end server! Now I can find more content about it. Thanks again!

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Thanks for the comment. They call it a back-end server! Now I can find more content about it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Single Page App requires a server to serve the `.css`, `index.html`, and `.js` files it requires. It is not a requirement that that an SPA must communicate with an application server via any means at all.

Your content can be static or self generated by the app itself. Should you require communication with a backend server, you can consume that via some sort of api over
protocols such as http, https, websockets or Server Side Events.

To summarize. An SPA can be completely self contained OR access an api to provide functionality. A standalone app requires a server only to serve the component files (.css, .js, .html) of the app itself.

Answer (score 4):

A SPA needs one server to serve the SPA bundle to the users browser.
If the SPA interacts with an API or APIs, the API(s) could be hosted on the same server that served the SPA bundle, or they could be hosted on other servers.

Comment: SPA's can be served without a server from an AWS S3 bucket or an Azure blob storage etc. so no server required necessarily.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer - S3/Azure would be acting as the server of the SPA bundle here.

Comment: @Adam - but would we call that an "Application Server," or just a "Web Server" or "Static Content Server"?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I think trying to pigeon-hole this terminology isn't terrible helpful to the OPs conversation. A server (in this context) "serves" something in response to an HTTP request, whether that something is static content (like a JS bundle), or JSON/XML/text from a database, or static images/css files, etc isn't really the point.  Perhaps this is best phrased as an IMO, I'm sure people will disagree with me.

Comment: @Adam - That's fair.  I don't necessarily have a strong opinion on categorizing servers in a rigid, semantic manner; I was more raising the question because I know some people do.  I was under the impression that perhaps this was the nature of the OP's question, but you are probably correct that this may just serve to be more confusing than helpful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

With SPA as well you will have html file and images, js, css files that will be loaded when you launch your single html webpage. So you need to host this  static content on some server. So it can be separate web server or same APIs
server(Application Server) which can host these static content and serve request for those files. It can be also hosted on cloud static server and distributed via CDN

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Yes. SPA apps do need to live somewhere (as you need to host the assets (js, css, initial html, other)

---

### Long Answer:

You need to setup somewhere to host the entry files as per the short answer. In the past I've used anything from:

- NodeJS code base services running on a Docker container (app & assets being served via express), to
- dotnetcore on a similar stack (With kestrel server serving the assets running on docker on ec2).
- Docker container running Apache webserver hosting the statically compiled assets

More recently I've dabbled with compiling the SPA app to a bunch of static assets (such as the ability [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) / [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/static-site-generator/#what-is-a-static-site-generator) provides with their tooling, but there are tons of others or alternatives in other SPA worlds)... but even then you'll need to host those assets somewhere.

- S3 on Amazon has the ability to host SPA apps directly via a bucket setting & providing an entry point
- Vercel (...or any other SaaS alternatives, Vercel is just where I host my personal stuff and has been easy to get going)

Again it's all up to you, but yes, you still need to make the JavaScript available somehow, you just need to pick your mechanic. SaaS with a baked in WebServer such as Vercel, a CDN like S3 that AWS provides, or go totally custom and spin up your own WebServer as application entry.